# NextJS with react-svg-loader fails

Tags: svg, webpack, next.js

I'm having trouble getting my configuration right for this. I have a NextJS setup with next-css and I'm trying to add react-svg-loader to the configuration:

next.config.js:

```
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");

module.exports = withCSS({
  cssModules: true,
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    importLoaders: 1,
    localIdentName: "[local]__[hash:base64:4]"
  },
  webpack(config, options) {
    const { dev, isServer } = options;
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: "react-svg-loader",
          options: {
            jsx: true // true outputs JSX tags
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    return config;
  }
});
```

The svgs will still fail to load:

> { Error: (client) ./svgs/pencil.svg 10:9 Module parse failed:
>   Unexpected token (10:9) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type.

Looks like my config above doesn't work but I can't quite figure out why.

Comment: Hi Matt Coady, you have found some solutions? Because i have the same problem

Comment: Ended up just pasting the raw svg into individual jsx components and exporting them as modules. Not a real fix but it worked for what I needed.

Comment: After several days of searching my solution was to do the same and apparently for now there is no other. Thanks for your feedback